# How to return a Serviceworker response body ReadableByteStream as Blob via PostMessage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, blob, postmessage, service-worker

I'm working with [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) in Chrome and am using postMessage to communicate between web page and serviceworker. Communication includes requesting and receiving file data (stored as Blob).

Let's say I'm storing a Blob like this:

```
// param.name = "http://foo.css",
// param.content = new Blob(
//   ["span%2C%20div%20%7Bborder%3A%201px%20solid%20red%20!important%3B%7D"],
//   {type: "text/css"}
// )

caches.open(CURRENT_CACHE)
    .then(function(cache) {
      request = new Request(param.name, {mode: 'no-cors'}),
      response = new Response(param.content);
      cache.put(request, response)
        .then(function() {
          event.ports[0].postMessage({
            error: null
          });
        });
```

This stores the file all right and I can use **fetch()** to retrieve it correctly instead of requesting it from the network. But if I use the **match()** method like so:

```
caches.open(CURRENT_CACHE)
  .then(function(cache) {
    return cache.match(param.name)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.clone().blob();
      })
      .then(function (converted_response) {
        if (converted_response) {
          event.ports[0].postMessage({
            error: null,
            data: converted_response
          });
        } else {
          event.ports[0].postMessage({
            error: {
              'status': 404,
              'message': 'Item not found in cache.'
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

I'm receiving a **ReadableByteStream** in the **response.body** and am stuck with it not knowing how to extract the content and pass it back via postMessage.

I'm currently trying to **clone()** the response as per [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/), because just returning the full response over postMessage will fail, throwing **DataCloneError: Failed to execute postMessage on MessagePort**, which I'm also not finding a lot of information on.

If I clone, I can call blob giving me a new(?) Blob, which I can then pass back but which only return undefined when trying to read:

```
var r = new FileReader()
return r.readAsText(my_blob);
```

If you want to try yourself:

To store the file in ServiceWorker, run this in its inspector console:

```
caches.keys()
  .then(function (list) {return caches.open(list[0])})
  .then(function (cache) 
      request = new Request("http://foo.css", {mode: 'no-cors'}),
      response = new Response(new Blob(
        ["span%2C%20div%20%7Bborder%3A%201px%20solid%20red%20!important%3B%7D"],
        {type: "text/css"}
      ));
      cache.put(request, response)
        .then(function() {
          event.ports[0].postMessage({
            error: null
          });
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      event.ports[0].postMessage({
        error: {'message': error.toString()}
      });
    });
```

To retrieve:

```
caches.keys()
  .then(function (list) {return caches.open(list[0])})
  .then(function (cache) {return cache.match("http://foo.css")})
  .then(function(answer) {
     console.log(answer.body);
     var b = response.body;
     return answer.clone().blob();
   })
  .then(function (x) {
      console.log(x);
      var r = new FileReader();
      return r.readAsText(x)
  })
  .then(function (y) {
    console.log("DONE");
    // undefined
    console.log(y);
  })
```

**Question**:
Any tips how to handle **ReadableByteStream** and extract it's content/mime-type as Blob so I can pass it back over postMessage? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I clone, I can call blob giving me a new(?) Blob, which I can then pass back but which only return undefined when trying to read:

```
var r = new FileReader()
return r.readAsText(my_blob);
```

That's because you are not using [`readAsText(my_blob)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) properly. You must attach a callback in the `onload` property of the file reader and resolve a promise when the callback is called. I mean, instead of:

```
.then(function (x) {
  console.log(x);
  var r = new FileReader();
  return r.readAsText(x)
})
```

Use:

```
.then(function (x) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = resolve;
    r.readAsText(x);
  });
})
```

> Question: Any tips how to handle ReadableByteStream and extract it's content/mime-type as Blob so I can pass it back over postMessage? Thanks!

To extract its mime type you can simply read the attribute [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/type) from the blob object.

```
.then(function (x) {
  console.log(x.type); // <-- the mime type
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = resolve;
    r.readAsText(x);
  });
})
```

Comment: good point. that worked and I'm getting out the content I was looking for. Only issue I'm having is the mime-type correctly being returned as header on my *match()* call, but I cannot pass it into the *blob()* call, so I'm ending with a readable blob thanks to you, but missing mime-type declaration. for another question. thanks for helping